# How to initiate the inactivity workstation lock?

Tags: security, winapi, interactive

If you call the **[LockWorkstation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation)** API, it immediately locks the workstation.

But when using something like the [**Machine Inactivity Limit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-machine-inactivity-limit) group policy, you have a grace period where:

- the screen blanks
- and [you have a default grace period of 5 seconds](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/221784/screen-saver-grace-period-bypasses-password-protection) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/Kn4vm))*
- before the workstation actually locks

(and this blanking happens even if the screensaver is disabled).

As far as i can tell, the existence of this grace period is an internal implementation detail, and even though it's value exists in the registry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ScreenSaverGracePeriod
```

It's use, or any other behaviors associated with the inactivity lock, I assume are internal implementation details.

How do I, as an application, trigger the same action that the inactivity lock triggers (so that what happens is what's supposed to happen)?

So rather than calling [**LockWorkStation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation), i want to call whatever Windows calls so that it:

- blanks the screen
- gives the grace period
- locks the workstation

## Update 11/10/2019

The Microsoft KB article [KB221784](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221784/en-us) is now completely gone from the Internet. Here it is reproduced:

> ## Screen saver grace period bypasses password protection
>
> ### Symptoms
>
> After you configure your computer to use a screen saver with a password, and after the screen saver has started, you may be able to bypass the password security and unlock the computer by pressing a key or by moving the mouse.
>
> ### Cause
>
> There is a delay between the time that the screen saver locks the computer and the time that the password protection is established. During this interval, you can use a key press or mouse movement to unlock the computer without having to type the password.
>
> ### Resolution
>
> **Windows NT 4.0 and Windows 2000**
>
> To resolve this problem in Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 and in Microsoft Windows 2000, reduce the screen saver password registration interval in the registry. To do this:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedt32**, and then click **OK**.
> 2. On the **Windows** menu, click **HKEY_LOCAL_ MACHINE** on **Local Machine**.
> 3. Double-click the **\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon** folder.
> 4. On the **Edit** menu, click **Add Value**, type **ScreenSaverGracePeriod**, click **REG_SZ** in the **Data Type** box, and then click **OK**.
> 5. Type a number representing the password activation delay (in number of seconds) in the **Data** box, and then click **OK**. You can enter any whole number between 0 and 2,147,483. The default entry is 5. If you use an entry of zero, there is no password protection delay.
> 6. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.
>
> **Windows XP and Windows Server 2003**
>
> To resolve this problem in Microsoft Windows XP and in Microsoft Windows Server 2003, reduce the screen saver password registration interval in the registry. To do this:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedt32**, and then click **OK**.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
>    ```
> 3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **String Value**.
> 4. Type **ScreenSaverGracePeriod**, and then press ENTER.
> 5. Double-click **ScreenSaverGracePeriod**.
> 6. Click **Decimal** under the **Base** heading, and then enter a number in the **Value data** box that represents the password activation delay in seconds.
>
>    You can enter any whole number between 0 and 2,147,483 (approximately 24 days). A value of zero indicates no password protection delay. There is no default entry.
> 7. Click **OK**, and then exit Registry Editor.
>
> Last Updated: Apr 19, 2018

Comment: This is all internal to winlogon.exe, with no public facing API.

Answer (score 1):

The windowsAPI wi help here...

GetLastInputInfo retrieves the time (in milliseconds) of the last input event.

To blank the screen:

```
HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112
SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170

SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
```

2 = Display off

Finally to lock the work station:

LockWorkStation api function

The LockWorkStation function is callable only by processes running on the interactive desktop. In addition, the user must be logged on, and the workstation cannot already be locked.

Comment: This is not quite what the OP is looking for. The OP wants to trigger the OS's native functionality for the policy, not implement each step manually.

Comment: AFAIK This is the only way to trigger this functionality, of course I would be happy to see another solution.

Comment: I am using **GetLastInputInfo**; that's how I know when to call **LockWorkStation**. What i'm trying to avoid is cargo-cult impersonations. For example, Windows doesn't guarantee that ScreenSaverGracePeriod is a thing; it's internal to WinLogon. I'm looking for the public-facing API.

Comment: Isn't the closest thing to said API the registry key behind the link you gave?